# How to disable gestures (lock - no move/pan/zoom) on mapView - here maps ios sdk/swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, here-api

How to Disable `mapView` gestures on iOS?

On Android:

```
mapFragment.getMapGesture().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just disable user interaction...

`mapView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`

Answer (score 5):

For anyone looking to disable movement of the gms map while still being able to add custom gesture recognizers, you can use the following code for Swift 4.1

```
gmsMapView.settings.tiltGestures = false
gmsMapView.settings.rotateGestures = false
gmsMapView.settings.zoomGestures = false
gmsMapView.settings.scrollGestures = false`
```

Answer (score 1):

The key is to disable zooms and scrolls, such as:

```
mapView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

This is Enough.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest SDK, you can switch off gestures:

```
mapView.settings.setAllGesturesEnabled(false)
```